# No such column on an sobject

Tags: soql

I am getting this error when running this SOQL query in Query editor in developer console:

No such column 'Credit_Card_Reference__c' on entity 'Case'

I checked the field, it is there under Case. And the field level security is set to be visible to every profile. Not to mention I am the system administrator.

This field is a lookup relationship field which has a lookup filter on it. But I don't see that could be preventing me from querying it.

Is there any other reason I am getting this error?

Comment: When you use a relationship name in a query, you must use the relationship names without the __c. Instead, append an __r (underscore underscore r).

Comment: @glls I am actually directly querying the Credit_Card_Reference__c field

Comment: Is the console opened and the instance which you are running refer to the same. These type of issue may occur when we open multiple sales force instances opened and field not present in all of those.

Comment: Namespace?......You sure you used two __ and not one _ - If managed with namespace did you assign a license to yourself?

Comment: @Eric It is not a managed package. We developed the object in the sandbox and deployed into Prod.

Comment: hmm....Seems like either permission or you are not connecting to the org you think you are in the dev console. If its there it should should up if those two are valid. Not too many cases (if any) of a field that is present meeting the conditions not being able to be queried..Keep in mind if the sys admin profile was not deployed then it will not have access to the field by default (but you'd they all had visibility so)

Comment: @Eric I actually I copy/pasted the api name from the field page. So it shouldn't be a typo.

Comment: going to be tough to diagnose outside of permissions and right org. Its pretty binary as far as issues go. Wish I had access to the org as it would make it much easier to help....but I digress

Comment: You sure you opened the correct org in the dev console? I've done that several times and had to explicitly logout of the orgs I didn't want it to be logged into.

Comment: What release is the sandbox currently on? I.e. Is it Summer '17 yet? What does the following SOQL return? `SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization`. Can you run your problem SOQL query from an independent tool, such as Workbench?

Comment: @DanielBallinger Actually, it only happens in our prod org which is Spring 17. And the NamespacePrefix is blank.

Comment: @LanceShi New Hypothesis! It isn't the `Credit_Card_Reference__c` lookup field that is causing the problem. Rather it is the sObject that the lookup refers to. Try checking the permissions on the target sObject. Possibly even the  Deployment Status of said sObject.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I was also excited about this when you told me so I checked. But unfortunately since I am the admin, I have all the access to that object.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm facing something similar.

Comment: Did you ever resolve it?